# Server not starting. "Cannot invoke "aag.f()"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

[image]
That is the error message I get in the logs.

I've tried to reinstall java and redownload the server file without success.

Tried googling the problem, but only found one reddit thread which didn't give an answer.

Comment: This is "Exception stopping the server", which suggests to me that this is not the first exception. Can you pastebin the full log and add it to your question?

Comment: Before that it likely said `*** FAILED TO BIND TO PORT!`.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find the Reddit thread, and it appears that the server could not start because the port was already in use.

Quit all other running Minecraft servers or change the port.

To change the port, open server.properties and replace `port=oldport` with `port=newport`.

When logging into the server change `address` to `address:newport`, or `address:oldport` to `address:newport`.

Answer (score -1):

Found the problem myself.

My IP was changed from 192.168.1.101 to 102 on my PC.